# Declared Variable as 1 to 3 but Debugger is showing it's value as 4

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Title says it all, I have no idea how this could even happen or what I can do to fix it. I have changed the variable to be defined as 1 to 2 and it still shows 4, I tried 5 to 10 and it still shows 4 as well. Doesn't seem to matter if it's even in the range I declared.

`For W = 1 to 3`

[image: Here is a screenshot of it from debugging]

I will post the rest of my code below, maybe it is something else in the sub causing an issue?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub FTG_Calculations()

    'Declare Variable
    Dim L As Double
    Dim Length As Double
    Dim OrderFTG As Double
    Dim UoM As String
    Dim W As Double
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Set frm = Forms!Frm_JobTicket
    
    'Set L equal to Length from Tbl_JobTicketMould
    L = DLookup("Length", "Tbl_JobTicketMould", "Access_ID =" & Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Part_Number)
    
    'Convert Length to Feet
    Length = (L \ 12)
    
    'Find Unit of Measure for this part
    UoM = DLookup("Unit_of_Measure", "Tbl_JobTicketUoM", "Access_ID =" & Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Part_Number)
    
    'If UoM is PCS then insert that number. Otherwise set equal to Quantity Ordered divided by Length of piece(in FT)
    If UoM = "PCS" Then Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket = Me.Quantity_Ordered Else: Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket = Abs(Int(Me.Quantity_Ordered \ Length))
    
    'Mupltiply Length times Quantity to get Order Footage
    OrderFTG = Int((Length * Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket))
    
    'Define limits of the loop. Then runs through all Wrap SQ FTG fields and inputs calculation
    For W = 1 To 3
    
       'If UoM is PCS then calculate Order Footage to find Wrap Sqaure Footage. Otherwise take slit size in FT and multiply by Order Quantity and Scrap Rate
    If UoM = "PCS" Then
    frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * OrderFTG) * (Round((frm("RIP_Scrap_Rate")), 3) + 1))
    Else: frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * frm("Quantity_Ordered")) * (frm("RIP_Scrap_Rate" + 1)))
    End If
    Next W

End Sub
```

Comment: After the loop, `W` = `4`.

Comment: As BigBen mentioned above, `Next W` increments (or decrements in other cases) the variable `W` by the `Step` value declared in the loop (defaults to 1 if omitted). That's how the loop knows when to stop. In your case after the 3rd iteration, its value is 4 and the loop stops.